# How to properly display records via Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the following record via JavaScript but it throws error:

```
this.state.entitiesx.data is undefined
```

In jQuery I can successfully get the **lemma** values from the record with the code below:

```
$.each(entitiesx.data.entities, function(k, v) {
  var value = v.lemma;
  var res_entities = "<span>" +
    "<span> " + value + "</span>" +              
    "</span>";
  $("#result_entities_append").append(res_entities);
});
```

Here is my React.js approach.

Error it throws:

```
this.state.entitiesx.data is undefined
```

How do I get the **lemma params/values** from the record?

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      entitiesx: [{
        "success": true,
        "data": {
          "content": "Michael Jordan.",
          "language": "en",
          "version": "sensei: 4.7.0; disambiguator: 16.0-QNTF-2017",
          "entities": [{
            "type": "ORG",
            "lemma": "National Basketball Association",
            "syncon": 206667,
            "positions": [{
              "start": 134,
              "end": 137
            }],
            "relevance": 15,
            "attributes": [{
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "league",
              "syncon": 36252,
              "type": "org"
            }]
          }, {
            "type": "NPH",
            "lemma": "Michael Jordan",
            "syncon": 436096,
            "positions": [{
              "start": 0,
              "end": 14
            }, {
              "start": 79,
              "end": 85
            }, {
              "start": 107,
              "end": 109
            }],
            "relevance": 11,
            "attributes": [{
              "attribute": "gender",
              "lemma": "male",
              "syncon": -1,
              "type": ""
            }, {
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "autobiographer",
              "syncon": 41500,
              "type": "nph"
            }, {
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "ballplayer",
              "syncon": 41549,
              "type": "nph"
            }, {
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "basketball player",
              "syncon": 41582,
              "type": "nph"
            }, {
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "entrepreneur",
              "syncon": 42572,
              "type": "nph"
            }, {
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "natural person",
              "syncon": 220500,
              "type": "nph"
            }, {
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "shooting guard",
              "syncon": 233044,
              "type": "nph"
            }, {
              "attribute": "role",
              "lemma": "spokesman",
              "syncon": 136019,
              "type": "nph"
            }]
          }],
          "knowledge": [{
            "syncon": 206667,
            "label": "organization.sport_association",
            "properties": [{
              "type": "DBpediaId",
              "value": "dbpedia.org/page/National_Basketball_Association"
            }, {
              "type": "WikiDataId",
              "value": "Q155223"
            }]
          }, {
            "syncon": 436096,
            "label": "person.author",
            "properties": [{
              "type": "WikiDataId",
              "value": "Q41421"
            }]
          }]
        }
      }]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        <div>
          <h3>List of Records</h3>
          <ul>
{this.state.entitiesx.data.entities.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.lemma}
             
              </li>
            ))}

          </ul>
        </div>
       

      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this.state.entitiesx.data` is indeed `undefined`.  `this.state.entitiesx` is an array:

```
this.state = {
  entitiesx: [/.../]
};
```

And an array has no property called `data`.  Perhaps you meant to map over that array?:

```
{this.state.entitiesx.map((ent, i) => (
  ent.data.entities.map((obj, j) => (
    <li key={`${i}${j}`}>
      {obj.lemma}
    </li>
))))}
```

(As an aside... If `obj` has a property that is expected to be unique, that may make a better `key` value than just the array indexes.)

Answer (score 1):

You just mistakenly made the value of **entitiesx** an array with a single object.  You likely just meant it to be an object.  Making the change below should lead to success.

```
this.state = {
  entitiesx: { // removed opening bracket ([)
    /*...*/
  } // removed closing bracket (])
};
```